# Custom keyboard with swipe functionality in android?

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-softkeyboard, android-keypad

I want a custom keyboard in android. I have referred many more examples and seen source codes on github but, couldn't found any relevant reference for swipe functionality.Now i want funcationality like if user want to write Hello World then it should only swipe on that words only like in some devices it gives by default. So, can anyone have any idea or suggestions regarding this, because i am facing first time this type of requirement. Thanks in advance. This below image is for what i actually want. [image: Hello World With swipe functionality]

Comment: Do you get solution of this problem?

Comment: Not yet. @snehadesai

Comment: This looks like an old thread. Were you able to discover a solution?

Comment: Not yet. @arjun

Comment: This is so unfortunate, practical projects are never vehemently discussed. Instead, everybody wants to rush debating some framework.